# How to put two container in a row in flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

[image]

> I Have wrapped two expanded view inside a row but couldn't manage to
> wrap. its going out of my screen layout.
>
> as a new comer in flutter technology, i appreciate someones help.

```
Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset('assets/images/checked.png',height: 24,width: 24,),
                    SizedBox(width: 5,),
                    Text('Gated Security',style: Constant.infoTextStyle,)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset('assets/images/checked.png',height: 24,width: 24,),
                    SizedBox(width: 5,),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('Individual slips and along-side docking',style: Constant.infoTextStyle,textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `maxLines: null` to your `Text` widget

Also Wrap your `Column` widget with `Expanded`

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: try wrapping your Column and Text widgets with expanded